# Show that the common ratio between any two consecutive terms of a geometric sequence is a constant r.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think I have to write some kind of proof for the question, but I am not sure how to actually write it. In some of my previous questions I used examples to write the proofs, but my lecturer marked them wrong because he wanted formal proofs. 
The question is: Show that the common ratio between any two consecutive terms of a geometric sequence is a constant r.

Comment: If you start writing it, you will immediately finish writing it.

Comment: @user547814 According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), **by definition** a geometric sequence is a sequence with common ratio $r$.

Comment: Your problem statement appears in the title and tacked onto the end of the body of the Question, but it is not a full statement.  To be in a position to prove something about a geometric sequence, one needs a definition of geometric sequence.  What you've asked "to write some kind of proof for" is commonly given as the definition of a geometric sequence.  Perhaps you are working with a different definition.  In any case you should check the definition and edit the Question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let the first term be $a$. Then, since this is a geometric sequence, we have the sequence will look like this $$a, ar, ar^2,...,ar^k,....$$ Of course, it follows that the common ratio of this sequence is $$\frac{ar^m}{ar^{m-1}}=r.$$